# Running TestCafe via Chromium on linux container

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In my `node` project, I use `TestCafe` runner in order to taken screenshots.
I use chromium headless, and it was perfectly in locally.
When I try to use it in a linux container, on `openshift`, i get:

```
Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.
```

I use node image and I've tried to set local installation of chrome in my project and it also didn't work. How can I make the TestCafe recognize any chromium browser (without the using of `testcafe-browser-provider`)?

Comment: Please check the [Troobleshooting](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/use-testcafe-docker-image.html#troubleshooting) section in our Docker guide and try the workaround suggested there (specifying the `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage` flags).  If it doesn't help, please clarify whether the issue is reproduced with headless Firefox?